# Scaling edges loop along themselves to a plane/grid

Tags: modeling, snapping

I have to move the edges loop along themselves and align them in a plane

Is it possible to achieve the same result as in this video on blender?

[scale constraints edges](https://imgur.com/a/n3bguGw)

[image: example]

Comment: Does selecting the loop, hitting G twice then dragging with the mouse achieve the result you want?

Comment: unfortunately no, I can't move the whole loop together

Comment: @Christian can't find one yet, myself, despite MVB's flattering comment.. Max's multi-constraint snapping is one of the things I miss about it, in Blender. That,  quick weighted selection for modelling instead of proportional editing, and Editable Mesh. The closest I can think of is to cut a new loop with Ctrl F > [Intersect(Knife)](https://imgur.com/a/mCQA4Zc) but that's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can come up with is to enable snapping in face mode with default settings:

[image]

Then moving the vertices one by one with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the tip, do you also know of a method to do this on the whole loop selection?

Comment: @Christian I would post that if I figured something, maybe R. Betts will know, if not vanilla then some addon.